# Foreign Keys in Web API 2 - Best practices?

Tags: entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Basically I'm writing an API using Web API 2 and Entity Framework on the backend.

The thing I'm unsure about is what to do in regards to foreign keys on my models.

Say I got a **person** property with a foreign key to an **order** property.

Sometimes the client needs the person property, sometimes it does not. How should I go about this?

Should I create 2 methods:
/api/person/1 <-- returns person without order
/api/personwithorder/1 <-- returns person with order

Seems like an awful lot of methods in my opinion.

I know the queryable attribute exists as well which provides support for the client to use the $extend argument to include properties at will - however I would rather not use the queryable attribute if I can avoid it.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: If you need two different things, why is having two methods an "awful lot"? You could pass in a flag parameter to return orders too

Comment: why not simply always return the person with the order property and let the client do with it as they will? or if that doesn't sit right add a flag on your call that if true will return the order property and if not will not?

Comment: @DavidG

Thanks. I ended up using flags to allow the client to specify whether to include the properties or not.

Comment: @theDarse

I didn't want to include the order always seeing as it would add unnecessary bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here are some options.

**Option 1**

Multiple methods in API

```
public Person GetPerson() { ... }
public Person GetPersonWithOrders() { ... }
```

**Option 2**

Pass a flag to the method:

```
public Person GetPerson(bool getOrders) { ... }
```

**Option 3**

You could use [`OData`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) to allow the caller to query the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Option one could make my API quite messy since it would expose a whole bunch of methods.
I like option 2 - I think I might go with that.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on DavidG's option 3 of using OData, here is how you'd do it:

1. `Install-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData`
2. Create a `PeopleController` inheriting from `ODataController`
3. Configure the Web API OData model like so:

   `modelBuilder.EntitySet<Person>("People");`
4. Define your `Get` method as returning an `IQueryable<Person>`
5. In your calling code, add the `expand` clause to the URL to specify the child object you would like to expose, like this: `/api/People(1)?$expand=Orders`

There's a little bit more to it around registering the OData route, but this is all standard configuration that you can find in any [sample project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-OData-cecdb524).

OData is really very flexible and takes care of tonnes of issues about how you should build your URLs.